# Tkinter NameError

Tags: python, tkinter

I am trying to make a simple program that can select programs and start them, but when I select a porgram from the list it gives a name error

```
from tkinter import *

class Window(Frame):
    def __init__(self, master=None):
        Frame.__init__(self,master)
        self.pack(fill=BOTH, expand=1)

        var=IntVar

        example=Checkbutton(self, text="example", variable=var, onvalue=1, offvalue=0, command=self.example)
        example.place(x=0,y=0)
        
    def example(self):
        if (example.get() == 1):
            print("1")
        elif (example.get() == 0):
            print("0")

root=Tk()
app=Window(root)
root.geometry("220x120")
root.resizable(width=False, height=False)
root.mainloop()
```

When I run this, it works fine but upon clicking the checkbox it gives the error

> NameError: name 'example' is not defined

i've tried searching with different keywords but haven't found a solution. The only progress i made was to remove the `(self)` from behind `def example`, which then gave the following error

> TypeError: example() takes 0 positional arguments but 1 was given

any help would be very appreciated

Comment: So, is ‘example’ a method, or attribute?

Comment: use self.example, or initialize example outside the __init__ function. but the best option is to use the "self"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a number of issues with your code:

- as pointed out in the comments, in order to have `example` be visible in the method, you either have to declare it globally, or you have to do `self.example`.
- in order to do `get()`, you want to work with the `IntVar` `var`, not with the Checkbox itself.
- then again, `var` needs to be `self.var` to be visible.
- finally, `var` needs to be an instance of `IntVar`, so you need bracket: `var = IntVar()`

All in all, with those changes applied, it would be:

```py
from tkinter import *

class Window(Frame):
    def __init__(self, master=None):
        Frame.__init__(self,master)
        self.pack(fill=BOTH, expand=1)

        self.var=IntVar()

        example=Checkbutton(self, text="example", variable=self.var, onvalue=1, offvalue=0, command=self.example)
        example.place(x=0,y=0)
        
    def example(self):
        if (self.var.get() == 1):
            print("1")
        elif (self.var.get() == 0):
            print("0")

root=Tk()
app=Window(root)
root.geometry("220x120")
root.resizable(width=False, height=False)
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: I did a quick test and this seemed to work, thank you.But I will work on the code tomorrow as it is very late

Comment: Is it possible you used the same `var` for both of them? that might cause this behaviour (without having checked it)